# Find the probability that the point P is closer to the centroid than the sides.

Tags: probability, geometry

> A point 'P' is picked uniformly at random inside a regular hexagon. Find the
> probability that the point P is closer to the centroid than the sides.

I came to know from this site that if that's a equilateral triangle, the formula is =3^(-1)–3^(-2)–3^(-3)
But how can I use this formula when the figure is regular hexagon ?

Comment: A circle doesn't sound right. You'll probably need some parabolas. Definitely draw a diagram and test a few points to get a feel for it!

Comment: In fact this is the $n=6$ case of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1706984